# How to write and save an XMl file in a Configured Location in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have the below code to write an XML.But it stores inside the Bin folder after successful run.
Question is:I want to store it in some specified Configurable Network location instead of Bin folder.
Any idea?

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<item><name>wrench</name></item>");

// Add a price element.
XmlElement newElem = doc.CreateElement("price");
newElem.InnerText = "10.95";
doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(newElem);

XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Indent = true;
// Save the document to a file and auto-indent the output.
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("data.xml", settings);
doc.Save(writer);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just simply pass a path there instead of data.xml

```
XmlWriter.Create("C:\MyFolder\data.xml");
```

Since you'd like it to be configurable, I'd suggest you use App.Config and ConfigurationManager to set the path you'd like.

Basically it'd look like this

(In your code:)

```
string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SaveFilePath"];
```

(App.Config:)

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="SaveFilePath" value="C:\BlaBla\data.xml"/>
      </appSettings>
</configuration>
```